# Last Login/Logout in on specified date

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking am using mysql to find a users login/logout details

The database looks like this:

```
Login TIME,
Logout TIME,
Date, DATE
```

So, I have a query that searches between two times ranges and a date.

Within this date range there could be multiple login/logout details so how could I grab the first login from the range and the last logout?

Comment: I think you'll need to give an example of what you mean by "two time ranges and a date" for searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Joachim and @Douglas have already said you should give more detail when asking a question. Include what you have tried so far and full table structures (output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE` is good).

Assuming that you have the user_id in this table you can use something like -

```
SELECT user_id, MIN(login), MAX(logout)
FROM tbl
WHERE ...
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: Yeah, will do next time...to be honest, I have my query down it was just that couldn't think of a way to get this data...it's been a long day. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is MySQL's MAX and MIN functions. They'll return the largest/smallest value in a data set, should accomplish what you're looking for.

Next time please spend a bit more time clarifying what you need and perhaps add an accurate database description (no ID numbers in your table presently, eh?)

Comment: Dually noted sir, it's my first time posting so wasn't even sure of the syntaxs and what is expected.